# Login implementation for web application consuming authenticated REST service

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

Maybe my question title is not clear, I try to explain:

I implemented an authenticated REST service using Spring MVC + Spring Security. I configured **Digest Authentication**, thus I need to include credentials in every request to the service.

Now I need to implement a web client for this service. In a classic web application I could implement a simple login form configuring FORM auhtentication, but in this situation I don't know which is the common approach to apply.

Since all requests require authentication, which resource should I call from an hypotetical login form? Should I implement a dedicated "login resource" to achieve this (i.e.: `/my-service/login`)?

**UPDATE**: my idea is to authenticate users at first access and then store credentials on client side to send them on every request. So what I have to define is a way to check user credentials at first request. Is there a standard way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

No need of login, in all requests include basic auth headers (username and pwd).
Make sure basic authentication is enabled in spring security config.

```
<http use-expressions="false">
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
<http-basic />
</http>
```